# Oracle 10g -> Create complex constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I should fix a problem in the DB tier, not in the code, but it's a bit complex. I googled, but couldn't find the solution :(

> DB version: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Prod

Okay, let's say I have a table with multiple row, but only these are interesting to us right now.

```
CREATE TABLE "TRANSPORT" 
(   "O_PREFIX" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "O_NUMBER" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "O_SUFFIX" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "OP_DAYS" VARCHAR2(7 BYTE), 
    "VALID_FROM" DATE, 
    "VALID_TO" DATE, 
);
```

- O_PREFIX+O_NUMBER+O_SUFFIX makes an Order ID like: AB2000S
- OP_DAYS: marks the days on which transport takes place, i.e.: 1235 -> means 1st day (monday), 2nd day (tuesday) and so on... if it ships every day, it would look like: 1234567, if only ships on Monday: 1
- VALID_FROM+VALID_TO: gives us the range where the shipment takes place. For example, if VALID_FROM: 01SEP13, VALID_TO: 14OCT13 and OP_DAYS is: 15, this means a shipment every Monday and Friday between 1st of SEPT and 14th of OCT.

For simplicity, lets call the first one "ID", 2nd one can stay OP_DAYS and "Range" the last one.

I have to make sure that no overlapping record is inserted. That means That ID AND OP_DAYS AND Range doesn't match.

- ID match is straight forward, they are the same String.
- OP_DAYS match means there is a common number, so for example "1234" and "456" matches in our case, but "123" and "456" wouldn't match.
- Range match means there is an overlap in the date, so for example "01SEP13-15SEP13" and "10SEP13-01OCT13" matches, but "01SEP13-15SEP13" and "16SEP13-01OCT13" is OK.

Above criteria has to be ALL met for the DB to reject the insert of the row. So there has to ba an ID match, an OP_DAYS mats and a Range match, and in this case, the data should be rejected.

One more thing: if it makes it easier I can make the OP_DAYS 7 columns, so every day would have it's separate column. This is only if it makes it really hard or impossible to make this constraint without this change.

Comment: Please, please don't use "NUMBER" as a column name. This will cause you a lot of pain in the long term.

Comment: The column name had a prefix (just like PREFIX and SUFFIX) in its name, I just removed it because I wanted to share the minimum of the project specific information that is not needed for this question :) But thanks for the heads up, you are right!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot enforce a rule like this with a constraint.  It can be done using triggers, which will be complex to code due to having to avoid the "mutating table" issue while still ensuring transaction integrity (so **not** using an autonomous transaction!)

There is also a method using materialized views with constraints that I have written about [here on my blog](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/2004/10/enforcing-complex-constraints-in.html) (see first example).  However, this is quite experimental and may not be practical in a real database (e.g. may adversely affect performance).

The most common solution is to write PL/SQL package APIs to perform the logic and force applications to use the API rather than inserting/updating the table directly.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will check this in detail Monday. I didn't think so either, that it is possible with constraints :(

Answer (score 2):

here is the AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE Trigger, which check  for intersection and raise an exception if one is found.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER transport_intersection_ck_trg
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE 
  ON transport
DECLARE
  cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) 
  INTO cnt
  FROM transport t1, transport t2
  WHERE t1.rowid != t2.rowid
  AND t1.PREFIX || t1."NUMBER" || t1.SUFFIX = t2.PREFIX || t2."NUMBER" || t2.SUFFIX
  AND 1 = CASE 
            WHEN INSTR(t1.op_days, 1) > 0 AND INSTR(t2.op_days, 1) > 0  THEN 1
            WHEN INSTR(t1.op_days, 2) > 0 AND INSTR(t2.op_days, 2) > 0  THEN 1
            WHEN INSTR(t1.op_days, 3) > 0 AND INSTR(t2.op_days, 3) > 0  THEN 1
            WHEN INSTR(t1.op_days, 4) > 0 AND INSTR(t2.op_days, 4) > 0  THEN 1
            WHEN INSTR(t1.op_days, 5) > 0 AND INSTR(t2.op_days, 5) > 0  THEN 1
            WHEN INSTR(t1.op_days, 6) > 0 AND INSTR(t2.op_days, 6) > 0  THEN 1
            WHEN INSTR(t1.op_days, 7) > 0 AND INSTR(t2.op_days, 7) > 0  THEN 1
            ELSE 0
          END
  AND  t1.valid_from >= t2.valid_to
  AND  t2.valid_from >= t1.valid_to
  ;        
  IF cnt > 0 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'intersection found');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know if we wan't to use trigger or not, but constraint is not possible, so I'll see next week what the solution will be.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use triggers to enforce data consistency. Write a module that perform database side validation.